# what does Restangular.all() return?

Tags: angularjs, restangular, mean-stack

Why do we have to use Restangular.all every time before making a request.

```
var messages= Restangular.all('posts');
var newMessage = {
  body: "Hello world"
};
messages.post(newMessage);
```

When I view 'messages' in console it shows an empty array.

1)What are the properties of 'messages'?

2)Is it an instance of collection.

Comment: Probably (if not obviously) ! Why don't you inspect its properties...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation: messages is just a restangular object which points to your messages resource uri on the server.

In order to see the messages you would need to call a method on messages such as getList() this will return a promise which you would then unwrap to find your list of messages.